# jquery - Replace background url not contained size

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to change to the URL of a background, but when I do this the `background-size` is not contained:

```
$(".blackline").css("background", "url(/images/floorplans/" + homes[param.id].floorplan + ") top center");
$(".blakcline").css("background-size", "contain");
$(".blackline").css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Typo:

$(".blakcline").css("background-size", "contain");

Change to $(".blackline...